# Restoring permissions from rsync backup

Tags: permissions, rsync

I am new to Linux.  I started using Ubuntu 18.04.4 a few weeks ago – a refugee from the land of Windows 7 – so please pardon the newbie question.

I have managed to get to grips with rsync somewhat to backup my home folder to an external hard drive.  I used the following command

```
rsync -ruhv - - delete /home/phill /media/phill/Backup/backup1
```

I have also managed to use Anacron tab to automate the process on a weekly basis and it has run three times.  The resulting backup folder looks to be a faithful copy of my home folder and appears to be working perfectly.

However, when I check the Permissions of the files on the external drive it says that I am not the owner.  As a test I copied one of the backed up files back to my home folder and the result was that I had read write access as the owner but the group and other permissions had down graded to read-only – not a major isue at this point as it is all on my personal desktop PC.

So the main question is, if my PC goes down for whatever reason and I have to reinstall Ubuntu will I be able to copy the files back to the new home folder and access them as the owner?  Obviously, I don’t want to rely on a backup that ultimaltely I can’t access properly.

It would be useful to know how to preserve permissions exactly. I have tried to research rsync options and got confused.   Will ‘rsync – a’ work and preserve all the permissions.  I did a simple test copying a single file with  cp - a  but it didn’t preserve the  group and others permissions but that is with a different command to rsync obviously.

Comment: What file-system did you copy it to?  Is it a file-system that allows saving all *posix* file data?

Comment: Make sure you do NOT use Microsoft filesystems when you do that. If " /media/phill/" is NTFS you will kill permissions as those are set -when mounting-.

Comment: I formatted the backup drive as EXT4.  I had seen advice on that one !

Comment: To answer your main question: you can always access the files on the drive if you have `sudo` rights, because you can always do `sudo chown -R phill:phill /media/phill`.

Comment: Thanks Jos, I'll get to grips with that.